# Create an index that increases after each gap in otherwise regularily-increasing row

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I've got a `samples` data frame which contains some readings at regularily-spaced timestamps (1 sec. interval).

```
                      TS           Pressure     Temperature
[...]
8  2014-08-26 00:18:26.8                105              30
9  2014-08-26 00:18:27.8                108              32
10 2014-08-26 00:18:28.8              109.9              31
11 2014-08-26 00:34:20.8                109              20
12 2014-08-26 00:34:21.8                100              24
13 2014-08-26 00:34:22.8                 95              22
[...]
```

I only have records during some events of interest (e.g. when `Pressure < 110`) and don't have any records outside of these events.

I want to give an unique ID to each "period" where `Pressure < 110`
I've made another data frame `EventBoundaryIndex` which holds the boundary indices of each period and the corresponding ID number:

```
> EventBoundaryIndex
     fromIndex  toIndex  eventID
1            1       10        1
2           11       30        2
[...]
```

read: event #1 should span from `samples[0:10, ]`, event #2 spans `samples[11:30, ]`, etc.
Now I would like to add an `eventID` row to my original `samples` data frame to indicate which `eventID` each record belongs to:

```
                      TS           Pressure     Temperature   EventID
[...]
8  2014-08-26 00:18:26.8                105              30         1
9  2014-08-26 00:18:27.8                108              32         1
10 2014-08-26 00:18:28.8              109.9              31         1
11 2014-08-26 00:34:20.8                109              20         2
12 2014-08-26 00:34:21.8                100              24         2
13 2014-08-26 00:34:22.8                 95              22         2
[...]
```

I tried:

```
samples$eventID[EventBoundaryIndex$from : EventBoundaryIndex$to] 
        <- EventBoundaryIndex$eventID
```

but that doesn't work.
I guess I need some form of `apply` but can't figure out the right way.

**Or**
If you can think of a simpler way to have my eventID index increasing each time  a "gap" of more than 1 sec is detected bewteen two consecutive timestamps, let me know!

Comment: `0` is not a correct index in `R`. It should be `1`.

Comment: Indeed! I've corrected it but still get the same problem.

Comment: @Ant You could have used `Map(`:`, EventBoundaryIndex[,1], EventBoundaryIndex[,2])`.  It seems like there is something missing in the example

Comment: @Ant Also, your code for the first row `samples$eventID[EventBoundaryIndex$fromIndex[1]:EventBoundaryIndex$toIndex[1]]# [1]  1  1  1  2  2  2 NA NA NA NA` gives an incorrect index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 samples$eventID <- cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(as.POSIXct(samples$TS))>1))
 samples
 #                      TS Pressure Temperature eventID
 #8  2014-08-26 00:18:26.8    105.0          30       1
 #9  2014-08-26 00:18:27.8    108.0          32       1
 #10 2014-08-26 00:18:28.8    109.9          31       1
 #11 2014-08-26 00:34:20.8    109.0          20       2
 #12 2014-08-26 00:34:21.8    100.0          24       2
 #13 2014-08-26 00:34:22.8     95.0          22       2
```

Comment: @Ant No problem.  It was good that you provided an option `Or`.  I didn't fully understand the other logic

Comment: I would hardly recommend to avoid the use of `T` to mean `TRUE`.

Comment: @Pascal  Thanks, I am trying hard to break that habit of using `T`